# MVC Exception to JavaScript Reroute

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I need to create an exception that will reroute from my MVC view to a Login screen.

```
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
  routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Login",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new {controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
  );
```

For some reason it can't be done in MVC when it's a javascript request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what @Gupta is trying to do is the following:

```
public class MyNewClass : MyBaseClass
{
    public MyExceptionClass() : base()
    {
        //other stuff here
    }
}

public class MyBaseClass : Controller {
  private bool isRoute;
  private bool isAuthenticated;

  MyBaseClass(){
    isReroute = MethodCheckReroute();
    isAuthenticated = MethodCheckAuth();

    if (isReroute || !isAuthenticated) {
      Response.RedirectToRoute("Login");
      throw new System.Web.Http.HttpResponseException(
      new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.ExpectationFailed));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I'm doing on my app:

```
int errorCode = 9999;         
if (isReroute) {
  this.Response.StatusCode = errorCode;
  Response.RedirectToRoute("Login");
  throw new System.Web.Http.HttpResponseException(
      new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.ExpectationFailed));
}
```

The this.Response.StatusCode uses your routing config and redirects the page to the desired view.

Answer (score 0):

In my code, I make a base controller which has initialized method which redirects to login when it's not authenticated.

you can write same thing different way and it will work.

```
public class BaseController :Controller
{
   protected override void Initialize(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
        {
            base.Initialize(requestContext);
            Test(); check the user
        }
}

public class TestController : BaseController
{
}
```

In the base controller you can do code that will work on all over application.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how you did it.

Comment: How are you accessing other controllers after the base initializes? Is this a persistent check?

Comment: you have access to everything HttpContext, RequestContext and ControllerContext. Remember it's fire before controller's actionresult. for post-controller code you need to use ActionFilterattribute.

Comment: @AnirudhaGupta I'm not following, can you please write some code for this.

Comment: You were talking about using ActionFilterattribute. I want an example of what you are trying to do.